# Capture SQL queries via Django debug toolbar

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm calling my Django application from the command line with curl.  I'm passing json in the request and collecting a response in json as well.

I have the Django debug toolbar installed.  Is there a way I could capture the SQL via the toolbar and return it with the rest of the json response?

Something like

```
@json_response
def index(request):
    try:
        ids = json.loads(request.read())['ids']
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest

    listing = MyModel.public().filter(id__in=[c.split('-')[0] for c in ids])

    prep_list = [ l.details(request) for l in listing ]

    return {'status_code': 0,
            'status_text': 'success',
            'sql_query_list: DjangoDebugToolbar.sql()
            'prep_list': prep_list }
```

Any idea what I'd put in replacement of `DjangoDebugToolbar.sql()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db import connection  
connection.queries
```

you can get de last query doing:

```
print connection.queries[-1]
```

or

```
print connection.queries.pop
```